# Get data from List<Object[]> in React

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot

As Back-end, I'm using Spring Boot.
I get a list of objects with that:

```
@GetMapping("/car/1")
public List<Object[]> findCarById()
{
    List<Object[]> los = entityRepository.getCarById();
    String title;
    Option option; List<Options> options= new ArrayList<Option>();
    for(int i=0; i<los.size(); i++)
    {
        title = (String) los.get(i)[0];
        option = (Option) los.get(i)[1];
        options.add(option);
    }
    return los;
}
```

As Front-end, I'm using react:
to retrieve the list of options of car with id = 1 , I tried that way:

```
var requestb = new XMLHttpRequest();
requestb.open('GET', 'http://localhost:8080/api/auth/car/1', false);
requestb.send(null);
console.log(JSON.parse(requestb.responseText));
```

But I don't get a json abject.
Could you please tell me what I missed ?. Big thanks.

Big Thanks

Comment: It seems a load event-listener is missing for the requestb.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest

Comment: work by dummy data json e.g `json-server` .To find out which part it is related to `Backend` or `frontend``

Comment: Refer [here](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_http.asp) for how to use XMLHttpRequest. But avoid using it, use [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) instead. Refer [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/react-axios-react) for example. Also avoid the use of raw `Object`s in java, use DTOs as long as possible. Use Postman to test if backend is working fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir about your replies. Just I have a question :  It's recommended to use `List<Object[]>` to retrieve data from an entity which has many associations (ManyToMany) with other entities or just use a simple call `@GetMapping("/car/1")
public List<Option> findCarOptionsByCarId()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case, try using DTOs for all associations.

```
public class CarDto
{
   private String model;
   private OptionDto optionDto;
   ...
}
```

Hope To Help.